# 404 on API call in Thinkster MEAN Stack Tutorial

Tags: express, mean-stack

I'm following [this Thinkster tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/opening-rest-routes) on building a reddit-esque web app using MEAN.

The tutorial instructs using `curl` to create a new post.

> `C:\root>curl --data "title=test&link=http://test.com" http://localhost:3000/posts`

However, I get this error in response:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<h2>404</h2>
<pre>Error: Not Found
    at C:\root\app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (C:\root\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)</pre>
```

I looked through those files, but all the references were just showing me what happens to the error...

**Here's some code**

/routes/index.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next){
    Post.find(function(err,posts){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(posts);
    })
})
router.post('/posts', function(req,res,next){
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(post);
    })
})
```

/models/Posts.js:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

app.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongod:localhost/news');
```

I feel like I did everything correct, except I wasn't sure where to place the additional routes in the routes index file, and similarly in `app.js`. But this seems negligible to me. I performed all the debugging I could think of but am stuck.

It should also be noted that this tutorial was perhaps not intended for use on a Windows machine. I had to install `curl` and do a few other things that perhaps wouldn't be necessary on a Linux or Mac. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm withdrawing from this question and removed my answer as I have no idea what is causing your problem.  My recommendation to you would be to learn a lot more about what is actually happening in your program rather than just following app generators and tutorials blindly without knowing anything about what they do or how they work.  In addition, when people ask for the code that's starting your server (which is in your app.js), don't take 19 hours to finally provide it.  Good luck solving your problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm just trying to get a simple API working. I thought I would be able to learn as I went through this tutorial. How else am I supposed to learn this stuff?

Comment: If you don't know what your code is doing and how it works, then you won't know how to fix or debug things when something stops working.  I personally started with a simpler hand built app and added things one at a time as I understood how they worked and how they hooked into the app.  I didn't start with a multi file app created by some generator with routers and databases until I understood the basics of request routing in Express.  You've tried to jump ahead 10 steps without knowing how any of the 9 before it work.

Comment: @frlan Sorry, I will update that. I just meant the folder I'm starting it from is the root folder of the site. I'm in Windows, so I don't think `root` is even a user. Or was there another reason you made that comment?

Comment: @TravisHeeter Hello! Could you please verify: are your routes handled correctly if you GET it with browser, and did you try RESTful POST variation with "curl -X POST --data "..." http://localhost:3000/posts"? Apart from it, I suppose this generated `app.js` could be misconfigured (according to it's absence in the tutorial).

Comment: @KidBinary I get the same 404 error from localhost:3000/posts. `app.js` is [automatically configured by express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). However, the tutorial did instruct us to [add a few lines](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/creating-schemas-with-mongoose) to require the model files (`Posts.js` & `Comments.js`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `module.exports` is called prematurely in **routes/index.js**. Move `module.exports = router;` to the bottom of your file, recycle your service, and try again.

Also there are issues with **app.js**. See below:

app.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Notice the differences starting here
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news', function(err,db){
    if (!err){
        console.log('Connected to /news!');
    } else{
        console.dir(err); //failed to connect
    }
});

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next){
    Post.find(function(err,posts){
        if(err){ 
            alert(err);
            return next(err); 
        }

        res.json(posts);
    })
})

router.post('/posts', function(req,res,next){
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){ 
            alert(err);
            return next(err); 
        }

        res.json(post);
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How do I recycle the service - just close the cmd window I used to `npm start` and run that again?

Comment: sorry, recycle as in stop your express app, and restart after changes were made. So yea, npm start. If you want your services to persist, i highly recommend pm2